# Пробел в первой ячейке Excel (CSV)

Tags: java, excel, csv

При генерации csv файла и последующем его открытии в excel получаю ошибку.
Решить ее удалось добавив в первую ячейку первым символом пробел.
Информации об этом я толком не нашел.
Почему, если первая ячейка начинается не с пробела, то возникают подобные ошибки? И соответственно, как с этим бороться?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Мало данных для осмысленного ответа. Нужен как минимум образец такого CSV.

Comment: Добавьте код. Как вы вообще генерируете CSV? Мы не Ванга)